# Pattern I'm trying to print is upside down

Tags: python, function

Ok, I know this is super basic, and I probably should know what i'm doing here, but I'm stuck trying to flip this dang triangle. I keep getting confused with which variable I need to swap.
This triangle starts with a single star and iterates down to form a full triangle. I need it to start big and work down to a single star. Somewhat like a funnel. Please and thank you, and please again.

Here's the code:

```
def up_arrow(arrow):
    char = arrow
    index = 0
    size = 6
    while index < size:
        spaces = " " * (6 - index)
        print(spaces + char)
        char += arrow * 2
        index += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you keep increasing `index` by 1, until it reaches 6 and you keep increasing the length of `char` with two `arrow`s, so that it ends at 6*2-1 `arrows`s. So, have you tried reversing that?

Start with a string of `size`*2-1 `arrow`s, set `index` to `size`, decrement `index` every iteration, and keep going until you reach 0, as well as removing two characters from `char` every time:

```
def down_arrow(arrow):
    size = 6
    index = size
    char = arrow * (size * 2 - 1)
    while index > 0:
        spaces = " " * (6 - index)
        print(spaces + char)
        char = char[2:]
        index -= 1


down_arrow('.')
```

Note that I've tried to stick with the way you wrote it originally, there's more optimal ways to achieve this.

For example, while still just printing this type of arrow, this function can do both:

```
def arrow(ch, size, up=True):
    for i in range(1, size + 1) if up else range(size, 0, -1):
        print(' ' * (size - i) + ch * (2 * i - 1))


arrow('.', 6)
arrow('.', 6, up=False)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you think the answer fully answers your question, please accept it with the check mark, so that it no longer shows as unanswered.